# Upload workds, but I can't access req.file in Node Express using Multer

Tags: node.js, express, file-upload, multer

The uploaded file is saved in the destination, but I can't access it in the express route.

Why might this be happening? It makes no sense to me...

**EDIT:** What I've noticed is that the console.log sometimes works, and sometimes doesn't... This is even weirder. If I upload a tiny file, it always logs. For larger ones, it randomly decides when to log. I wonder what the problem might be.

**Client**

```
async function uploadFile(file) {
    console.log("file", file);

    let formData = new FormData();

    formData.append("file", file);
    formData.append("recordUid", recordUid);
    formData.append("fieldUid", fieldUid);

    await fetchPostFile("/api/files", formData);
}

export async function fetchPostFile(url, formData) {
    try {
        let result = await (
            await fetch(url, {
                method: "POST",
                withCredentials: true,
                credentials: "include",
                headers: {
                    Authorization: localStorage.getItem("token"),
                },
                body: formData,
            })
        ).json();

        return result;
    } catch (err) {
        return err;
    }
}
```

**Server**

```js
const express = require("express");
const router = express.Router();
const path = require("path");
const fs = require("fs");
const multer = require("multer");

const { getUidForTable } = require(`../utils.js`);

let filesFolderPath = path.join(__dirname, "../../../files/");

const storage = multer.diskStorage({
    destination: filesFolderPath,
    filename: async (req, file, cb) => {
        cb(null, await getUidForTable("recordDataFile", 20));
    },
});

const upload = multer({
    storage: storage,
    limits: { fileSize: 1024 * 1024 * 10 }, // 10 mb
});

router.post("/api/files", upload.single("file"), async (req, res, next) => {
    try {

        console.log(req.file, req.body); // <------------ NOTHING IS LOGGED

        res.status(200).send({ success: true });

    } catch (err) {
        next(err);
    } finally {
        req.connection.release();
    }
});
```

Comment: Everything seems fine except some issues which I guess you ignore to copy all codes here. Did you try with something else like Postman? Did you try to move this part of code to your app(root)?

Comment: What I've noticed is that the console.log sometimes works, and sometimes doesn't... This is even weirder. If I upload a tiny file, it always logs. For larger ones, it randomly decides when to log. I wonder what the problem might be.

Comment: Ok, maybe sometimes your machine is low on memory and couldn't log anything (due to buffer size). Have you tried to run in debugging mode and watch `req.file`?